# text in textbox shows up as circles instead of regular characters?

Tags: asp.net, css

When i type in either of the textboxes i get little circles appearing instead of text. Why is this happening and how do i stop it?

Code is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Foods.MainPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link id="Link1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/mainStyle.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class = "userIDTboxDiv">
        <div class = "userIDTboxText">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Enter User ID:
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox id="userIDBox" TextMode="password" runat="server" Height="52px" 
            Width="200px" />
    </div>
     <div class = "passwordTboxDiv">
        <div class = "passwordTboxText">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Enter User Password:
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" TextMode="password" runat="server" Height="52px" 
            Width="200px" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body 
{
    text-decoration:none;
    background: white; 
}
input 
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}




.userIDTboxDiv
{

    padding-top: 20%; 
    padding-left: 45%; 
    width: 15%; 
    height: 30%;
}

.userIDTboxText
{
    padding-left: 17%; 
    height: auto; 
    width:203px; 
}
.passwordTboxDiv
{

    padding-top: 2%; 
    padding-left: 45%; 
    width: 15%; 
    height: 111px;
}

.passwordTboxText
{
    padding-left: 10%; 
    height: auto; 
    width:203px; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess this has something to do with it:

```
TextMode="password"
```

in your `<asp:TextBox>` elements.  Remove the `TextMode` or change them to:

```
TextMode="SingleLine"
```

which happens to be the default.